# Prevent eclipse from moving to line of code while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, decompiling

While debugging if you press `F6` you move from one line to the next one. This is usually a good thing.
The problem arrives when the next step is within a decompiled class (I am using **JD-Eclipse** to decompile classes). The code of that class is sometimes as follows

```
(686)    /*      */     }
(687)    /*  967 */     boolean recordDeleted = false;
(688)    /*  968 */     for (String guid : guidLst)
(689)    /*      */     {
```

The debugger knows that you are on the line 687 and places the green cursor there, but that is not the actual line of the class; in this case it would be 967. Then I have to scroll all the way up to the real line and sometimes it costs a lot of time.

Is there a way to prevent eclipse from moving me through the code?

Comment: AFAIK debugging decompiled classes can get really tricky. I think your source code is not in sync with the byte code.

Comment: As they are not sync, how can I tell eclipse not to go through the lines of code while debugging? Anyway, how can I sync them without the source?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21730971/3082272

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I already new that. My actual problem is something different: I don't want to be redirected to the line eclipse thinks i am in, because it is not the right one

Comment: Sure, but you can configure JD-Eclipse, so the debugger can show you the correct line in the decompiled code by rearranging the lines depending on the original line numbers!

Comment: @bobbel That was a good one! Can you put it as an answer, so that I can accept it

Comment: Even if the answer lasted four month - here you go! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decompile the class files with the option **add line numbers as comments** and
you will be able to realign the code with **JD-Eclipse**, see: http://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/

You won't be able to decompile with line numbers if the class files are compiled with the flag `-g:none`:

> **-g:none**
>      Do not generate any debugging information.

Also see: [Eclipse skipping lines while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730835/eclipse-skipping-lines-while-debugging/21730971#21730971)

Comment: This works! As a remark: In the sourceforge website of this project someone says that it doesn't work wih java7, I have java7 and it worked fine.