# Eclipse skipping lines while debugging

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I am new to  both java and eclipse, I have been trying to debug an android app on a device. It is a small project with a jar file reference. I read similar questions but they didn't help.

What I need is to be able to debug the source codes of the jar file so I attached the source codes ( which I obtained using a decompiler ) and I am able to go into source codes of the library so I thought I did that correctly. But I can not succeed in debugging into these source codes; in debug mode it skipps breakpoints (only the ones in the source files which are attached to jar file) and when I try to 'step into code' it goes to random lines skips lines when debugging.

I am using the latest versions of eclipse, android sdk and jdk. I don't know what causes this problem and I'd like to know.

Thanks in advance, I hope I explained sufficiently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that you can't decompile the class files to debug it. Because the lines of the decompiled files will differ to the original Java source code lines (imagine: the real source code has some comments and other things which will not be compiled into class files)!

So, if your Eclipse shows you the current debug line `42`, then it only tells you, that the debugger will present you the `42th` line of code in the class file. This won't match your decompiled java source file.

However, you could decompile the class files with the option **add line numbers as comments**. These line numbers in comments you can compare to the actual stacktrace line numbers. This could help you a little bit to imagine the issue.

**edit:** as **Laurent B** recommended, you will be able to realign the code with **JD-Eclipse**, see: http://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/

+1 for the comment! :)

**edit2:** You won't be able to decompile with line numbers if the class files are compiled with the flag [-g:none](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options):

> **-g:none**
>       Do not generate any debugging information.

So if this is the case: try to find the original source code of your jar file!

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. But it is not likely to happen i fear. I would use the originals if I had them! :) But thank you for explaning.

Comment: +1 for add line numbers as comments, i learned something good today. see http://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/

Comment: Thanks again **Laurent B** too, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A decompiler will not get the exact source code but will try to recreate it from the generated bytecode.

This is an entropic process so Decompile(Compile(Source)) will not output Source (you loose information) such as line number. That is why you will need the original source code. If you don't have it, you will have to use your immagination to be able to follow the code :)

EDIT : apparently some decompiler tools can do that for you as stated by bobbel.
see [jdeclipse plugin](http://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/).

Comment: well, I feared this. I don't know if I can find the original sources. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Its shows that the source file and Jar is not same. Try to get the right version of Source.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your code line by line by pressing `F6`

Comment: I tried it, the breakpoints in the jar source files are never hit so I end up debugging the upper layer-i need to debug the jar file- which is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Decompiled source code sometimes acts like that. Unfortunately, the only solution for you is to stop debugging the jar and search the web for the source code and add it to your project.